# Using Path Connectedness Theorem to prove path connectedness for a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

There is a theorem stating that continuous image of path connected set is also path connected.

So how would you apply it for a set like S = $ \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}| f(x) = x^{3} \} $ to prove path connectedness using that theorem? I am a bit stuck here.

Comment: The theorem implies that the image under the function $f(x)=x^3$ of a path connected set is path connected.

Comment: Sorry I meant for a set, not just the function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mean the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R ^2\colon \ y = x^3\}$. In this case you could define a continuous function $F \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ by $F(x) = (x,x^3)$ and write the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R ^2\colon \ y = x^3 \} $ $= \{(x,x^3) \in \mathbb R ^2\colon \ x \in \mathbb R\}$ as $\{F(x)  \colon x \in \mathbb R\} = F(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: So if I write $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^{2}$ given by $f(x,y) = (x, x^{3})$ is continuous. Continuous image of a path connected set is path connected and the image of $f$ is the set $S$. 

Is that enough to say?

Comment: Yep -- if you are sure path-connectedness is preserved by continuous images!